# Storing a short date in a DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to store a shortened date (mm/dd/yyyy) into a DateTime object.  The following code below is what I am currently trying to do; this includes the time (12:00:00 AM) which I do not want :(

```
DateTime goodDateHolder = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

Result will be 10/19/2009 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DateTime` is an integer interpreted to represent both parts of DateTime (ie: date and time). You will always have both date and time in `DateTime`. Sorry, there's nothing you can do about it.

You can use .Date to get the date part. In these cases, the time will always be 12:00 but you can just ignore that part if you don't want it.

Comment: Ditto. Further, Date format strings essentially allow you to ignore parts you're not interested in. For example, Compare two dates using the same format string of `{ MM/dd/yyyy}` and the time is not used. Note that we are actually comparing strings but we pretend we're comparing date objects.

Comment: @radarbob: almost. We're actually comparing integers which have been parsed from a longer integer, but the spirit of what you're saying is correct.

Answer (score 4):

You only have two options in this situation.

1) Ignore the time part of the value.

2) Create a wrapper class.

Personally, I am inclined to use option 1.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `.Now` you can use `.Today` which will not remove the time part, but will only fill the date part and leave time to the default value.

Later on, as others pointed out, you should try to get the date part ignoring the time part, depending on the situation.

Comment: DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() still has the time as 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 3):

A DateTime will always have a time component - even if it is 12:00:00 AM.  You just need to format the DateTime when you display it (e.g. goodDateHolder.ToShortDateString()).

Answer (score 1):

You'll always get the time portion in a DateTime type.

```
DateTime goodDateHolder = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

will give you today's date but will always show the time to be midnight.

If you're worried about formatting then you would try something like this

```
goodDateHolder.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")
```

to get the date in the format that you want.

This is a good resource [msdn-dateformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) based off the Java Joda Time library.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime object stores both the date and the time.  To display only the date, you would use the DateTime.ToString(string) method.

```
DateTime goodDateHolder = DateTime.Now;
// outputs 10/19/2009
Console.WriteLine(goodDateHolder.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

For more information on the ToString method, follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Comment: In most cases it's better to use ToShortDateString, so that the date component uses the localized format.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to get it as a DateTime object...but when you want to display it you can format it in the way you want by doing something like.

myDateTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy") which gives 10/19/2009 for your example.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is merely a UInt64 with useful and clever formatting wrapped around it to make it appear like a date plus a time. You cannot eliminate the time element.